# torch.CharStorage doesn't read data from a file when size isn't provided

Tags: lua, torch

I'm trying to replicate the example provided [here](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/storage.md#torchtypestoragefilename--shared--size--sharedmem). In my case, though, when I do the `torch.CharStorage('hello.txt')` I get `[torch.CharStorage of size 0]`. Here's the full output

```
$ echo "Hello World" > hello.txt
$ th

   ______             __   |  Torch7 
  /_  __/__  ________/ /   |  Scientific computing for Lua. 
   / / / _ \/ __/ __/ _ \  |  Type ? for help 
  /_/  \___/_/  \__/_//_/  |  https://github.com/torch 
                           |  http://torch.ch 

th> x = torch.CharStorage('hello.txt')
                                                                  [0.0001s] 
th> x
[torch.CharStorage of size 0]
```

I also noticed that when I do `torch.CharStorage('hello.txt', false, 11)` the data is read correctly. However, in [documentation](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/storage.md#torchtypestoragefilename--shared--size--sharedmem) the `shared` and `size` parameters are specified as optional. Is it the case that the documentation is not up to date or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be running into [distro bug #245](https://github.com/torch/distro/issues/245), introduced by commit [`6a35cd9`](https://github.com/torch/torch7/commit/6a35cd9a7073ec16596afb7116ecef5802844f30). As stated in [torch7 bug #1064](https://github.com/torch/torch7/issues/1064), you can work around it by either updating your `pkg/torch` submodule to commit [`89ede3b`](https://github.com/torch/torch7/commit/89ede3ba90c906a8ec6b9a0f4bef188ba5bb2fd8) or newer, or rolling it back to commit [`2186e41`](https://github.com/torch/torch7/commit/2186e414ad8fc4dfc9f2ed090c0bf8a0e1946e62) or older.

Comment: Yes, my `pkg/torch` is currently between these two commits. Do you know if I will need to rerun the `torch/install.sh` script after updating to `89ede3b `?

Comment: @MaxShvets Yes, you will. But if you just run it as-is, it will undo your update. The quick/easy fix is to comment out [the line with `git submodule update --init --recursive`](https://github.com/torch/distro/blob/0219027e6c4644a0ba5c5bf137c989a0a8c9e01b/install.sh#L50) first.

Comment: I didn't get the chance to try out your suggestion yet, but I'm pretty sure that the reason for this problem is as you described. I'm going to accept your answer